# VBA - Select particular Column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for an alternative to this code. I need to select 1st and 5th column only

```
Sub Copy()
        Dim Source As Worksheet
        Dim Target As Worksheet
        Dim valsArray As Variant

        valsArray = Array("A,B,C") '<--| define your values to be filtered on Source sheet column A
        ' Change worksheet designations as needed
        Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        With Source  '<--| reference Source sheet
            With .Range("A1:A1000")  '<--| reference its range from A1 to A1000
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=valsArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues   '<--| filter referenced range on its first column with values stored in valsArray
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than
                    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 5).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Target.Range("A1") '<--|copy filtered cells skipping headers and paste in target sheet from cell A1
                End If
            End With
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    End Sub
```

here in this part i have written `.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 5)` which selects from 1st column to 5th column but i need only 1st and 5th column.

is there any way to get only those column ?

Thanks

Comment: Note that `Array("A,B,C")` is an array with only one entry. You probably meant to use `Array("A","B","C")` with 3 distinct entries instead.

Comment: use union for multiple ranges

Comment: Have you tried using something like `Range("A1:A1000,E1:E1000")` ? e.g. `Range("A1:A1000,E1:E1000").Select` would select first 1000 cells of columns 1 and 5 (A and E)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i have used 3 distinct entries only

Comment: @ Foxfire And Burns And Burns Range("A1:A1000,E1:E1000").Select  will select the columns i need to copy it in another sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 separate .Resize lines into A1 and B1

```
  .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Target.Range("A1")
  .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Target.Range("B1")
```

Comment: This worked for me Thanks @user1302114.My apologies in the delay in getting back to you.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i used 2 seperate .Resize lines as mentioned 
1st Resize will copy the 1st column and paste it in mentioned sheet from "A1"
2nd Resize will copy the 5th column and paste it in mentioned sheet from "B1"